# How to parse query parameters in Java that works with all delimiters?

Tags: java, url, design-patterns, query-string

So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448999/query-string-delimiters) answer, it seems that any character can be used to separate query parameters in a URL.

Hence a regex matcher for `&` delimiter, such as the following, will fail when `;` or `|` or something else is used for example:

```
private static final Pattern MATCHER = Pattern.compile("name=([^&#]*)");
```

So is there a GENERIC way of extracting query parameters from a URL, given that ANY valid delimiter could have been used in that URL ?

Comment: Don't write your own parsing code for something the runtime environment provides a parser for. It is very likely to be superior to anything you could write.

Answer (score 1):

just change your pattern to '([^&#;|]*)', if you want to deal with ';' and '|'.